# Zip from command line with Windows 11

Tags: cmd, zip, windows-11

What is the cmd tool for zipping files with the new Windows 11 feature ? (The one used by default by explorer).
I tried zip, 7zip, compress...

Thank you

Comment: Lol, how is asking about the cli usage of a software not a programming problem? It was closed without even a comment...

Comment: @Klesun Using a CLI is not programming. Using commandline tools is not programming. Trying to identify where a tool is located or how it is called is not programming. And nobody left a comment, because once a question is closed, it receives a blue note saying why it is closed.

Comment: Got nothing in this world is a programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CMD tool for zip handling on [newer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows) Windows 10, thus I presume carried over to Win 11 is [TAR](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html), however it is not "The one used by default in explorer", since that system inbuilt feature has been there, since I think, at least XP"

Windows system uses a variant of bsdtar

> [bsd]**TAR**  creates and  manipulates streaming archive files.  This implementa-
> tion can extract from tar, pax, cpio, **zip**, jar, ar,  xar,  rpm,  7-zip,
> and  ISO  9660  cdrom  images  and  can create tar, pax, cpio, ar, **zip**,
> 7-zip, and shar archives.

HOWEVER I have not tested if windows version includes all those other formats such as 7-zip, but zip works well.

see `Tar -h`

```
tar(bsdtar): manipulate archive files
First option must be a mode specifier:
  -c Create  -r Add/Replace  -t List  -u Update  -x Extract
Common Options:
  -b #  Use # 512-byte records per I/O block
  -f <filename>  Location of archive (default \\.\tape0)
  -v    Verbose
  -w    Interactive
Create: tar -c [options] [<file> | <dir> | @<archive> | -C <dir> ]
  <file>, <dir>  add these items to archive
  -z, -j, -J, --lzma  Compress archive with gzip/bzip2/xz/lzma
  --format {ustar|pax|cpio|shar}  Select archive format
  --exclude <pattern>  Skip files that match pattern
  -C <dir>  Change to <dir> before processing remaining files
  @<archive>  Add entries from <archive> to output
List: tar -t [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, list only entries that match
Extract: tar -x [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, extract only entries that match
  -k    Keep (don't overwrite) existing files
  -m    Don't restore modification times
  -O    Write entries to stdout, don't restore to disk
  -p    Restore permissions (including ACLs, owner, file flags)
bsdtar 3.5.2 - libarchive 3.5.2 zlib/1.2.5.f-ipp
```

To list use `Tar -tf file.zip`

To extract use `Tar -m -xf file.zip`

To compress use `Tar -a -cf new.zip files`

Other options are available as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Your machine has PowerShell.

From cmd.exe:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command Compress-Archive
```

From a PowerShell console:

```
Compress-Archive
```

For information use:

```
help Compress-Archive -Full
```